# Does every line through the origin come arbitrarily close to some other lattice point?

Tags: irrational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

Given positive real numbers $x$ and $\epsilon$, do there necessarily exist positive integers $p$ and $q$ such that $\left| qx - p \right| < \epsilon$?

Or geometrically: in a two-dimensional Cartesian plane, does every line through the origin come arbitrarily close to some other lattice point? (I realize that that's not *exactly* equivalent to the algebraic version, but if either is true than both are.)

I feel pretty certain that the answer must be "yes", but I'm not managing to prove it. My initial reaction was that it should be a direct consequence of the fact that the rationals are a dense subset of the reals; but that really only shows that we can satisfy the weaker condition that $\left| x - \frac{p}{q} \right| < \epsilon$, or equivalently, that $\left| qx - p \right| < q\epsilon$.

(This question was inspired by [this recent answer on the Space Exploration Stack Exchange](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/58948/846).)

Comment: Related: [Prove that every ray through the origin eventually meets one of the discs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008906/prove-that-every-ray-through-the-origin-eventually-meets-one-of-the-discs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this follows from a pigeonhole argument.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem