# Can a line with an irrational slope be arbitrarily close to the integer lattice?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, number-theory

Suppose on a plane, we have a line $f(x)=kx $ with k irrational. Does this statement hold?

> $\forall \epsilon, \exists (p,q)\in \mathbb{N}^2, |f(p)-q|<\epsilon $.

Let $\pmb{IR} $ be the set of all irrationals for which the statement holds, is the following correct?

1. $\pmb{IR}=\Bbb{R}-\Bbb{Z} $.
2. $\pmb{IR} = \emptyset$.

If both don't hold, how large is this set (in different meanings of largeness or size, e.g., Lebesgue measure)?

Comment: You may want to check the [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem).

Comment: $|f(p)-q|=|k-\frac{q}{p}|\cdot p<\epsilon$

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Prove that every ray through the origin eventually meets one of the discs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008906/prove-that-every-ray-through-the-origin-eventually-meets-one-of-the-discs).

Comment: As $\Bbb Z$ is the set of integers, not rationals, neither statement 1 nor 2 is true. The set of rationals is commonly denoted by $\Bbb Q$.